# React Native - How to create a draggable hovering element

Tags: react-native

as the title says, I'm trying to create a hovering element; I have found a very good tutorial on how to make a drag and drop element, but I wanted to know how to do it with other views on the page, and to make that draggable element hover above the others when being dragged. Thanks !
(PS : I am asking this because I know `overflow` doesn't work on Android)

Answer (score 0):

[react-native-interactable](https://github.com/wix/react-native-interactable) has features for this out of the box.